# After replacing GPU, there's no output to the monitor

Tags: gpu

I've replaced my GPU and rebooted PC. I didn't have any output from PC on the monitor ("divice is not connected; move the mouse on computer") but the videocard is functional.
So I read suggestions and deleted the drivers with my old video card installed, now I reboot the PC and neither old nor new one work. 
Any help?

Comment: How do you know that the new card is functional? Does the old card give any signs of life? Both cards should show the BIOS/UEFI startup screen when connected properly. Check the cable connection on monitor side, you may have disconnected it accidentally.

Comment: The old video card IS functional, but after uninstalling drivers it won't display anything, even BIOS

Comment: BIOS doesn't depend on drivers and the boot screen should show up if the card is functional and connected properly.

Comment: Replacing DVI cable fixed everything. SOLVED.

Comment: @user1078719, was the cable bad? Was it incompatible? If you can figure out exactly *why* it didn’t work (e.g., it was a single-link DVI cable where you needed dual-link or it was a digital DVI cable where you needed a digital+analog cable or something), then you can type up the explanation as an answer below and accept it, then if anyone happens to have the same problem and finds your question while searching for a solution, they can see your answer and fix it too. `:-)` Plus, you’ll get some points for the good detective work.